# Apache subdomain not working

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I'm running apache on my local machine and I'm trying to create a subdomain, but it's not working.  Here is what I have (stripped down):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/one
   ServerName one.localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/two
   ServerName two.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I recently added `one`.  The `two` entry has been around for a while, and it still works fine (displays the webpage when I go to `two.localhost`).  In fact, I copied the entire `two.localhost` entry and simply changed `two` to `one`, but it's not working.  I have tried each of the following:

```
* `apachectl -k graceful`
* `apachectl -k restart`
* `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
* `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop && !#:0 start`
```

Apache will complain if `/var/www/one` does not exist, so I know it's doing *something*, but when I visit `one.localhost` in my browser, the browser complains that nothing is there.  I put an `index.html` file there and also tried going to `one.localhost/index.html` directly, and the browser still won't fine it.  This is very perplexing since the entry I copied from `two.localhost` is *exactly* the same .. not only that, but if something were wrong I would expect to get a 500 rather than the browser not being able to find anything.  The `error_log` also has nothing extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is 'one.localhost' in your `/etc/hosts` - Verify resolution with `ping one.localhost`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive also? You need that to tell Apache that "*:80" is a name-based virtual host, instead of an IP address-based virtual host. See the difference here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Also, have you tried running `apachectl -t` to perform a syntax check on the config files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at your server access log file. If you did not find any record that matches your source IP and requested URL, then you are not reaching your server using this subdomain..

One point you did not talk about is the DNS name resolution of `one.localhost`. You need either to define an `A / CNAME` record in your DNS server to respond to resolve requests of `one.localhost` or at least you need to add a new entry in `/etc/hosts` file on your client machine (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` in Windows machines).

If you are able to reach your server, then most probably it is a configuration issue. You need to look at the overall configuration not just a small part. Also, you may have some rewrite rules/.htaccess files, etc...